# Django: how to annotate based on only domain name and entire url with query params?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am using django and I am trying to come up with a query that will allow me to do the following,

I have a column in the database called `url`. The `url` column has values that are very long. Basically the domain name followed by a long list of query parameters.

Eg:

```
https://www.somesite.com/something-interesting-digital-cos-or-make-bleh/?utm_source=something&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=biswanyam%20report%20-%20digital%20cos%20or%20analog%20prey&ut
http://www.anothersite.com/holly-moly/?utm_source=something&utm_medium=email&tm_campaign=biswanyam%20report%20-%20digital%20cos%20or%20analog%20prey&ut
https://www.onemoresite.com/trinkle-star/?utm_source=something&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=biswanyam%20report%20-%20digital%20cos%20or%20analog%20prey&ut
https://www.somesite.com/nothing-interesting-bleh/?utm_source=something&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=biswanyam%20report%20-%20digital%20cos%20or%20analog%20prey&ut
```

I want a django query that can basically give me an annotated count of urls with the same domain name regardless of the query parameters in the URL.

So essentially this is what I am looking for,

```
{ 
 'url': 'https://www.somesite.com/something-interesting-digital-cos-or-make-bleh', 'count': 127,
 'url': 'http://www.anothersite.com/holly-moly', 'count': 87,
 'url': 'https://www.onemoresite.com/trinkle-star', 'count': 94,
 'url': 'https://www.somesite.com/nothing-interesting-bleh', 'count':72
}
```

I tried this query,

```
Somemodel.objects.filter(url__iregex='http.*\/\?').values('url').annotate(hcount=Count('url'))
```

This doesn't work as expected. It does an entire URL match along with the query parameters instead of matching only the domain name. Can someone please tell me how I might accomplish this or at least point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might not be possible because you cannot group by some partial information on a certain field. If you really want to achieve this, you might want to consider changing your schema. You should store `url` and `parameters` separately, as 2 model fields. Then you would have a method or if you want to make it look like an attribute, use `@property` decorator, to combine them and return the whole url. It wouldn't be too hard to split them in a migration/script to fit the new schema.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the schema is not an option. There must be a way to accomplish this although I believe the solution might be a bit esoteric. Still looking for answers!